# Hover de um select com javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Bom dia, preciso criar um hover em cada opção dos selects e não estou conseguindo fazer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse select é feito desse jeito.

```
                  <select id="valorFiltro" style="width:350px" class="browser-default custom-select"> </select>
```

Função que gera as opções.

```
                for (let index = 0; index < allLinhas.length; index++) {

                    var textoFormatado = allLinhas[index].split(' - ');
                    var linha = textoFormatado[1];

                    $('#valorFiltro').append(
                        ' <option value="' + allLinhas[index] + '"> ' + linha + '</option> '
                    );
                }
```

Eu precisava que quando passasse o mouse por cima(hover) da opção mostraria o value da linha sabe.
Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o atributo `title` do HTML, que automaticamente é colocado um `tooltip` com o texto que você colocar, que no caso é o mesmo que você colocou no `value`.

```
          for (let index = 0; index < allLinhas.length; index++) {

                var textoFormatado = allLinhas[index].split(' - ');
                var linha = textoFormatado[1];

                $('#valorFiltro').append(
                    ' <option value="' + allLinhas[index] + '" title="' + allLinhas[index] + '"> ' + linha + '</option> '
                );
            }
```

Fonte: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp

Comment: Era exatamente isso o que eu queria. Muito obrigado